# Finding Rows with Equal Values, Comparing their Columns and Removing the Smaller Value's Line

Tags: awk, sed, editing

I have the following line of code:

```
grep -nP ';MULTIALLELIC' biallelic.output | sort -k2 | awk -F'[:;\t]' '{print $1,$3,$9,$13}'
```

It outputs:

```
2374 213 MID=212 GO=1
2462 213 MID=477 GO=137
2394 233 MID=232 GO=1
2464 233 MID=668 GO=1070
2185 24 MID=23 GO=1
2465 24 MID=752 GO=1083
2146 48 MID=354 GO=1010
1893 48 MID=47 GO=1
2219 58 MID=57 GO=1
2463 58 MID=595 GO=1057
```

---

I need to compare GO values based on the value found in the second column. Whichever row has a larger GO value I would like to remove that line number from the original file.

---

By adding `awk '{print>$2}'` I am able to separate the lines based on the value in column two but I am trying to avoid writing results to files.

What am I missing?

**Edit: I am actually trying to remove those lines from biallelic.output, not just print what lines I want to remove. Sorry for the confusion.**

Comment: are you comparing GO values with each other or with $2?

Comment: With $2. I want to compare all the rows with equal values found in $2. So in my example I would compare lines 1 and 2 since they both have a $2 value of 213. Then compare those lines' GO values and remove the second line from biallelic.output since 1037 > 1.

Comment: to make it crystal clear, change second row's GO value to 137.

Comment: however, you're not really removing any records but just reporting what needs to be done.  My guess is you want a file with these records removed, not?

Comment: I would actually like to remove those lines, thats' my fault for the confusion. Question has been edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will compare GO values with each other and list the records with higher values compared to the minimum value.

```
$ sed 's/GO=/& /' file | 
  sort -k2,2 -k5n      | 
  awk 'a[$2]++{if(!h) print h="Lines Removed From biallelic.output";
               print $1}'

Lines Removed From biallelic.output
2462
2464
2465
2146
2463
```

header will be conditionally printed if there is no value reported.

splits the last field to separate the number from the prefix for sorting, group values by second field and sort by GO values numerically.  The first for each group is the minimum, report all except the first for each group.

to get the filtered output

```
$ sed 's/GO=/& /' file | 
  sort -k2,2 -k5n      | 
  awk '!a[$2]++ {sub(/GO= /,"GO="); print}'

2374 213 MID=212 GO=1
2394 233 MID=232 GO=1
2185 24 MID=23 GO=1
1893 48 MID=47 GO=1
2219 58 MID=57 GO=1
```

Comment: This works great, thank you.  Is it possible to pipe the line numbers in $1 into sed to remove them from the original file? Something like `sed  '{}d'` 

If that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure I understood.  The second script gives you a the output with the unwanted records filtered out.  Do you want to remove the first field (`$1`)?  If so do `print $2,$3,$4`, instead of `print`.

Comment: The first field is just the line numbers from biallelic.output. If you remove the `!` from your code and run it again then print $1 then the result will be the lines I wish to remove from the original biallelic.output. I didn't post the entirety of biallelic.output since most of it isn't being modified.